# how to deal with datatable-ajax cannot be displayed using server-side

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, datatables

i am trying to display data on my database in laravel using datatable-ajax with server-side but the data i fetched is not displayed in the table

I've tried the json data on the url and it works but it can't appear on datatable-ajax

[json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui35N.png)

this is the script i'm trying to build using ajax
`
function getData(first_reload) {

```
        var id = <?= $customer->id ?>;

        /** Remove */

        if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#datatable-ajax')) {
            $('#datatable-ajax').DataTable().destroy();
        }

        $('#datatable-ajax tbody').empty();


        $('#datatable-ajax tfoot th').each(function(index, value) {
            var title = $(this).text();
            if (index != 0) // id and action
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
        });

        var table = $('#datatable-ajax').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: `{{ url('/') }}/customer/show-datatable/${id}`,
            order: [
                [3, "desc"]
            ], //or asc 
            columns: [{
                    data: 'id',
                    name: 'id'
                },
                {
                    data: 'no_resi',
                    name: 'no_resi'
                },
                {
                    data: 'total_fee',
                    name: 'total_fee'
                },
                {
                    data: 'date',
                    name: 'date'
                },

                {
                    data: 'bayar',
                    render: function(data, type, row) {

                        var paid = false;

                        $.each(row.statuses, function(key, val) {

                            if (val.id == 5)
                                paid = true;
                        });

                        if (paid) {
                            return '<span class="text-success">Sudah</span>';
                        } else {
                            return '<span class="text-danger">Belum</span>';
                            // <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon updatebayar_view"><i class="la la-check"></i></a>
                        }

                    }
                },
                {
                    data: 'sampai',
                    render: function(data, type, row) {

                        var paid = false;

                        $.each(row.statuses, function(key, val) {

                            if (val.id == 4)
                                paid = true;
                        });

                        if (paid) {
                            return '<span class="text-success">Sudah</span>';
                        } else {
                            return '<span class="text-danger">Belum</span>';
                            // <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon updateambil_view"><i class="la la-check"></i></a>
                        }

                    }
                },
                {
                    data: 'ambil',
                    render: function(data, type, row) {

                        var paid = false;

                        $.each(row.statuses, function(key, val) {

                            if (val.id == 7)
                                paid = true;
                        });

                        if (paid) {
                            return '<span class="text-success">Sudah</span>';
                        } else {
                            return '<span class="text-danger">Belum</span>';
                            // <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon updateambil_view"><i class="la la-check"></i></a>
                        }

                    }
                },
            ],
            fixedHeader: true,
            scrollX: true,
            initComplete: function() {
                // Apply the search
                this.api().columns().every(function() {
                    var that = this;
                    $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change clear', function() {
                        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                            that
                                .search(this.value)
                                .draw();
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });



    }
```

`
this is a view of my problematic table
[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PM7r.png)

Comment: Please create a [mre] to help make it easier for the community to find a solution. Start with no code, and then add only the absolute minimum amount of code which shows the problem. Also, provide a small sample of JSON data for testing, in the question (not in a link, not as a screenshot, and not as JavaScript - but as formatted JSON text).

Comment: You can also read [ask], take the [tour] and browse other relevant topics in the [help].